# Apparent different variable scoping rules for different variable types

Tags: python

I came accross this **gotcha** when writing a crude memoized function; the two snippets below illustrate the issue:

#### Snippet1

```
__foo = {}
def foobar(val):
    if not val in __foo:
        __foo[val] =123
    else:
        print ('Found!')
```

#### Snippet2

```
__foofoo = None
def foofoo(val):
    if not __foofoo:
        __foofoo =123
    else:
        print ('Exists!')
```

#### Command line

```
>>> foobar('1')
>>> foobar('1')
Found!
>>> foofoo(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foofoo
UnboundLocalError: local variable '__foofoo' referenced before assignment
```

Why is it that scoping rules appear to differ (`__foo` found, but `__foofoo` not found), depending on the variable type?

Comment: It's not because of the variable types. `foofoo` assigns to the variable, which makes it local. `foobar` doesn't assign to the variable, so it looks for it in the outer scope.

Comment: Try changing the first line of the second example to `__foofoo = {}` at the top and you'll get the same error.

Comment: In `foobar` you're not assigning to the variable, you're assigning to an element in the dictionary.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the clarification.

Comment: When you assign with __foofoo = 123, python interpreter assumes that it is a local variable so the if above this uses it as local instead of reaching the global one. Comment the assign and you'll see the if working with the global.